# Where clause in SQL server 2012 is influencing the rounding behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I understand that the FLOAT datatype can be inaccurate, but why does the below query return different rounded results for my `DeptCategoryScore` if I add or remove the WHERE clause `WHERE sub2.DeptID=210059`?

```
SELECT Sub2.DeptID,
   Sub2.CategoryID,
   Round(Avg(CAST(PersonAverage AS FLOAT)), 0) AS 'DeptCategoryScore'
FROM   (SELECT Sub1.PersonId,
           Sub1.CategoryId,
           Sub1.DeptId,
           Avg(CAST(PersonSum AS FLOAT)) AS 'PersonAverage'
    FROM   personsum AS Sub1
    GROUP  BY Sub1.PersonID, Sub1.CategoryID, Sub1.DeptID) AS Sub2
WHERE sub2.DeptID=210059
GROUP BY sub2.DeptID, sub2.CategoryID
ORDER BY sub2.DeptID, sub2.CategoryID
```

I would expect that the inaccuracy would work the same way, irrespective if I filter for a specific DeptID or would like to have the query return all DepIDs/CategoryID combinations at once.

When looking into a specific instance of getting 88 vs 87 as a DeptCategoryScore, I found the exact value behind was 87.499999999... Still funny somehow that adding the WHERE clause makes it 88, and leaving it out will round to 87.

Also I experimented with `WHERE sub2.DeptID BETWEEN 100000 AND 300000`, and constantly increased the upper boundary. I found that the score changes at a certain point after obviosuly too many DepIDs are included.

Please share some insight if you have an assumption or explanation for this.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/khen1234/2005/05/13/floating-point-fun/

Comment: My guess is the shape of the execution plan changes with or without the DeptID equality filter, and there is a tipping point with `BETWEEN` where the plan changes too. The approximate value may differ depending on where/how the aggregation occurs in the plan.

Comment: Also you really want an average of averages?  That will make the PersonSum for a (PersonID,CategoryID,DepartmentID) group with one row count the same as (PersonID,CategoryID,DepartmentID) group with 1000 rows.